# How to disable auto group codo in one line for a short function?

Tags: clang-format

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b) {
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

The above code is indented like this by the following command. I'd like to keep its original style (if it is one line, the output is one line, if the input is three lines, the output should be three lines.) Is there a way to do so with `clang-format`?

```
$ clang-format -style='{IndentWidth: 8, UseTab: Always, SpaceBeforeParens: Never, IndentCaseLabels: true }'
```

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) { return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b); }
```

Comment: Perhaps `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None` will do the right thing?

Comment: I tried with `clang-format -style='{IndentWidth: 8, UseTab: Always, SpaceBeforeParens: Never, IndentCaseLabels: true, AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None }'`. But it still folds everything in a single line. Here is the version info `$ clang-format -version
clang-format version 7.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final)
`

Comment: OK. It works. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `input.cpp`:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b) { return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b ); }
```

This is the result of using `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None`:

```
% clang-format -style='{AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None}' input.cpp
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
  return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);
}

% clang-format --version
7.0.1
```